# vuejs how and when to properly get the brand name by ID

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rest

I have an API that can return product details but it shows the brand by its ID,
I can also request the list of brands which has the brands and their IDs

I've been trying to display the actual name in my template and not the ID and I keep running into problems, the data is not being reactive propery and i can only get it to load sometimes after vite does a HMR update

I also want to do this with an array of vendor objects which contain the ID and name of each of our vendors
(each product has an array of vendor IDS from which this product is available to purchase)

is thee something in missing in my code to make this work or am i just being an idiot

```
<script setup>

import priceGraph from "../components/priceGraph.vue";
import { ref, computed } from "vue";
import { useProductsStore } from "../stores/products";
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import axios from 'axios'


const store = useProductsStore();

const route = useRoute()

let id = route.params.id
let link = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/" + id

const deets = ref({
  name: "Loading",
  description: "Loading",
  brand: "loading", // this is brand ID
  brandname: "Loading", // this needs to be the brand name to be rendered
  sku: "Loading",
  asin: "Loading",
})

store.fetchProducts()
store.fetchVendors()
store.fetchBrands()

const vendorNames = store.vendors
const brandNames = store.brands
console.log(vendorNames, brandNames)

async function getDeets(link) {
  try {
    const data = await axios.get(link)
    deets.value = data.data;
    console.log(deets.value)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
getDeets(link)


const brand = computed(() => brandNames.find((b) => b.id === deets.brand))
console.log(brand.value)

</script>


<template>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="back">
      <button @click="$router.go(-1)">Back</button>
    </div>
    <div class='deets'>
      <h1>Product Details</h1>
      <hr>
      <!-- <h2>ID: {{ deets.id }}</h2> -->
      <h2>Name: {{ deets.name }}</h2>
      <h3>Description: {{ deets.description }}</h3>
      <h2>Sku: {{ deets.sku }}</h2>
      <h3>brandID: {{ deets.brand }}</h3>
      <h3>brand name: {{ deets.brandname }}</h3>
      <h3>Asin: {{ deets.asin }}</h3>
      <h3>Date added: {{ deets.added }}</h3>
      <h3>Last updated: {{ deets.updated }}</h3>
      <hr>


    </div>
    
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: technically i should have the api return this info using a join or something, i still havent figured that out (django)

Comment: Could you clarify the problem please? What variable isn't reactive? What are you expecting?